# confusing in type conversion and giving unexpected result

Tags: java

```java
public class Multicast {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println((int) (char) (byte) -2);
    }
}
```

I am confuse about the type conversion and also giving unexpected result (it prints 65534, not -2 as expected).

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Define what _unexpected result_ does mean.

Answer (score 4):

The confusing result is due to the fact that `char` is an unsigned type. When `-2` is converted to `char`, its bit representation becomes `1111111111111110` in binary, because [two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) representation is used. That representation becomes a positive `65534` when converted to decimal - [the result you see printed by your program](http://ideone.com/I6gsgW).

Answer (score 0):

In Java, [`char` is an unsigned type](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2.1) (and `byte` is a signed type). So `(char)-2` is `65534`. Then you widen that to be an `int`.

Answer (score 0):

your confusion on the results of your code is partly due to sign-extension. I'll try to add a more detailed explanation that may help with your confusion.

```
char a = '\uffff';
byte b = (byte)a;  // b = 0xFF
```

this DOES result in the loss of information. This is considered a narrowing conversion. Converting a char to a byte "simply discards all but the n lowest order bits".
The result is: `0xFFFF -> 0xFF`

char c = (char)b;  // c = 0xFFFF

Converting a byte to a char is considered a special conversion. It actually performs TWO conversions. First, the byte is SIGN-extended (the new high order bits are copied from the old sign bit) to an int (a normal widening conversion). Second, the int is converted to a char with a narrowing conversion.
The result is: `0xFF -> 0xFFFFFFFF -> 0xFFFF`

```
int d = (int)c;  // d = 0x0000FFFF
```

Converting a char to an int is considered a widening conversion. When a char type is widened to an integral type, it is ZERO-extended (the new high order bits are set to 0).
The result is: `0xFFFF -> 0x0000FFFF.` When printed, this will give you 65535.